# Handler SDL event

Tags: python, events, sdl

From python process run c++ application with SDL, i call `self._process.send('p')` to send key 'p' to c++ application to pause it, but it not working. Any body can help me?!

This is code from c++ application to handler SDL event

```
while(!quit)
{
    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                printf("Quit adsplayer\n");
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_q:
                    printf("Quit adsplayer\n");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case SDLK_p:
                    pause = !pause;
                    printf("Adsplayer toggle to pause\n");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) instead of if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)). The way you did it you were just reading one event per game loop.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry @jofra, i forget while loop. I had been updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @DuHuynh You missed the point. You need 2 loops. One is while(!quit) as you did. And the SDL_PoolEvent should be on a while loop as well! Cause the waqy you did it you are just polling the first event, and you want to poll them all. Just take the if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) and make it a while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)).

Comment: I don't think so, with current code it work fine when i press key broad. It doesn't work when i send key from Python script. I need handle event from here. Thanks

Comment: Cant help you then sorry. But good luck trying to figure that out. Btw it should still be in while loop in my opinion. Even the wiki has a code example (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent).